# Sql query filling daily gaps from a date range result

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, grouping

I'm struggling to write an sql query on SQL Server 2016.

I have a Table T_Values that contains for each row a date and a value.
The date are not continuous from a daily basis (can have gaps).
I would like to create a query returning a continuous historical data and having the last known value on this gaps as follow:

Date

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Value</th> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>01.01.2017</td>
    <td>100</td> 

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>03.01.2017</td>
    <td>105</td> 
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>05.01.2017</td>
    <td>109</td> 
  </tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Value</th> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>01.01.2017</td>
    <td>100</td> 
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>02.01.2017</td>
    <td>100</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>03.01.2017</td>
    <td>105</td> 
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>04.01.2017</td>
    <td>105</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>05.01.2017</td>
    <td>109</td> 
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>06.01.2017</td>
    <td>109</td> 
  </tr>
</table>
```

I can obviously use temporary tables, but I'm looking here for a nice solution. I would like it as simple as possible and with good performances if possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Can be done via an OUTER APPLY and an ad-hoc tally table

**Example**

```
Select  [Date] = IsNull(B.D,A.Date)
       ,A.Value
 From  (
        Select *,D2 = lead(Date,1,Date) over (Order by Date) 
         from YourTable
       ) A
 Outer Apply (Select Top (DateDiff(DAY,A.Date,A.D2)) D=DateAdd(DAY,-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select Null)),A.Date) From  master..spt_values n1 ) B
```

**Returns**

```
Date        Value
2017-01-01  100
2017-01-02  100
2017-01-03  105
2017-01-04  105
2017-01-05  109
```